# Java data pattern capturing

Tags: java, gesture

I'm developing gesture recognition algorithm using IMU in Java. I was wondering how to to it most effective way. One idea that came to my mind is to capture data patterns from IMU and store it, then use this data to find closest match when I perform the gesture with IMU. Can you please help me how to do it?

Comment: Please provide more details, otherwise this may get closed on SO for being either "unclear" or "too broad".

Comment: I have development board based on STM32F0 and i'm reading data from IMU and sending it trought USART. I have written java app where i'm recieving this data. Basically I want to do gesture recognition using data from IMU using some kind of machine learning where my java program stores data patterns from IMU and then use this stored data to recognize gesture and then use this data to recognize gestures as i perform them.

Comment: I suggest you break this up into multiple questions. As a single question, this is definitely beyond the scope of SO. For example, how to efficiently store the data patterns is highly dependent on the type of the data. Also, since you tagged this as 'java', many people here will not know your domain at all. Like, say, what is IMU? what is STM32F0? Then, the machine learning is an entire episode on its own: should you be doing clustering? supervised classification?

I am not trying to dissuade you from using SO. Just trying to explain how you might get the best out of it.